# How can I install Celestia on Ubuntu 18.04.1?

Tags: 18.04, software-installation

Like the title said, I want to install Celestia. I already downloaded the packages [from the official page](https://celestia.space/download.html) and then, I tried all the things that I found on some posts (also, they're outdated, cause the last one is for Ubuntu 16.04) but nothing works.

How can I install it on Ubuntu 18.04.1?

Comment: Are you really running 18.10? Please edit your question to add the result of the terminal command: `lsb_release -d` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: my fault... sorry

Comment: "I tried all the things I found" is not detailed enough to help us. Please tell us what you tried, and what led you to believe that each attempt failed. I once found a blog claiming that soaking my keyboard in vinegar was a great idea, so "all the things I found" might have some rather mixed advice.

Answer (score 5):

You can install Celestia by compiling sourcecode by following below steps.

Install dependencies and required packages.

```
sudo apt install qtbase5-dev-tools qtbase5-dev libqt5opengl5-dev qtchooser libglu1-mesa-dev libpng-dev libjpeg-dev libtheora-dev liblua5.3-dev build-essential
```

Clone Source code from repository.

```
git clone https://github.com/CelestiaProject/Celestia
```

Compile Source Code. It will take long time 5-10 mintes.

```
cd Celestia && mkdir build && cd build
qmake -qt=5 PREFIX=/opt/celestia -o Makefile ../celestia.pro
make
```

Install Celestia.

```
sudo make install
```

Comment: Small typo, the last package should be `build-essential` and not `build-essesntial`.

Comment: Follow below steps to install it on most recent version of Ubuntu:


`git clone https://github.com/CelestiaProject/Celestia && cd Celestia && git submodule update --init && sudo apt install qtbase5-dev-tools qtbase5-dev libqt5opengl5-dev qtchooser libglu1-mesa-dev libpng-dev libjpeg-dev libtheora-dev liblua5.3-dev build-essential libglew-dev libgl1-mesa-dev libeigen3-dev libfmt-dev cmake
 && 
mkdir build && cd build && 
cmake .. -DENABLE_QT=ON && 
make && 
sudo make install`

Sorry for the cramped command. Can't write a full answer due to community protection.

Comment: on ubuntu 19.04 mkdir build and cd build and the qmake line in this answer above have to be replaced by: sudo apt-get install libglew-dev libfmt-dev libeigen3-dev gettext cmake && rm CMakeCache.txt && cmake . && make && sudo make install Then you can start celestia by typing celestia-qt

Answer (score 2):

To install Celestia in 18.04, open a terminal and do:

```
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/simbd/Scripts_Ubuntu/master/Celestia_pour_Bionic.sh && chmod +x Celestia* && sudo ./Celestia*
```

Celestia will then be available in 'Show Applications' or you can launch it from the terminal with:

```
celestia
```

Comment: If my answer has been helpful, please accept it: https://askubuntu.com/tour Then we may then also use it as the "already answered".

Comment: The script isn't available anymore. And I wouldn't run some random script as root anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I was not able to change travel speed in 1.7 (<kbd>F1-F5</kbd>, <kbd>A</kbd>,<kbd>Z</kbd>), other people do not report problem.

## 1. Development snapshot - repository 1.7

Follow instructions in [INSTALL.md - github](https://github.com/CelestiaProject/Celestia/blob/master/INSTALL.md) or [opensuse](https://software.opensuse.org/download.html?project=home:munix9:unstable&package=celestia)

Note: I had to download key manually.

#### Adding launcher to favorite apps bar

copy icon to icons folder

```
# sudo cp ../src/celestia/qt/data/celestia.png /usr/share/icons/hicolor/128x128/apps # for source -see below 
sudo cp /usr/share/celestia/celestia-logo.png /usr/share/icons/hicolor/128x128/apps/celestia.png
```

make .desktop file

```
cat >$HOME/.local/share/applications/celestia.desktop <<'EOL'
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.7.0
Type=Application
Name=Celestia
GenericName=Space simulator
Comment=Open source space simulator
TryExec=/usr/bin/celestia
Exec=/usr/bin/celestia
Categories=Astronomy;Science;Qt;
Icon=/usr/share/icons/hicolor/128x128/apps/celestia.png
MimeType=application/x-celestia-script
Terminal=false
EOL

cd $HOME/.local/share/applications/

chmod +x celestia.desktop
```

Adding to favorites

```
cat >addToMenu.sh <<'EOL'
#!/usr/bin/env bash
STATE=`gsettings get org.gnome.shell favorite-apps`
STATE=$(sed 's/]/,'\ \'celestia.desktop\'']/g' <<< $STATE)
gsettings set org.gnome.shell favorite-apps "${STATE}"
EOL

bash addToMenu.sh
```

## 2. version [1.6.1](https://bintray.com/celestia/releases-deb/celestia/view/readmore#)

Follow instructions in [link](https://bintray.com/celestia/releases-deb/celestia/view/readmore#read)

## 3. version 1.6.2 beta

```
#Download beta tar.gz from:
https://github.com/CelestiaProject/Celestia/releases

sudo apt install libgtk2.0-dev
sudo apt install libgtkglext1-dev
sudo apt install liblua5.3-dev
    
tar xzvf Celestia-1.6.2-beta3.tar.gz 
cd Celestia-1.6.2-beta3

libtoolize
autoreconf -f
./configure --with-gtk
make
sudo make install

which celestia # for .desktop
# /usr/local/bin

# for logo, see above
find -name "celestia-logo.png"
#../src/celestia/gtk/data/celestia-logo.png
```

## 4. development version from source 1.7

In addition to the previous answer `qt` libraries, I had to install:

```
sudo apt install libglew-dev libeigen3-dev libluajit-5.1-dev
sudo apt install libgtk-3-dev libfmt-dev libtheora-dev libjpeg-dev
```

clone as in previous answer

```
git clone https://github.com/CelestiaProject/Celestia
cd Celestia && mkdir build && cd build
```

install with cmake

```
cmake -o Makefile ../
make
sudo make install
```

In celestia.desktop file, use:

```
TryExec=/usr/local/bin/celestia-qt
Exec=/usr/local/bin/celestia-qt
```

For the record, I had to completely uninstall anaconda (source only).