# How to install Celestia on 19.10

Tags: apt, gnome, 19.10, configure, autoconf

[Celestia](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/celestia-common-nonfree) still doesn't have binaries for 19.10
The other option is to [build from source](https://askubuntu.com/a/1105374/197910).
I've downloaded the source of [1.6.2-beta2 from github](https://github.com/CelestiaProject/Celestia/releases/tag/1.6.2-beta2).
Installed needed packages written [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1081299/how-can-i-install-celestia-on-ubuntu-18-04-1). plus gettext said [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/182143/40417). so the needed packages was:

```
sudo apt install qtbase5-dev-tools qtbase5-dev libqt5opengl5-dev qtchooser libglu1-mesa-dev libpng-dev libjpeg-dev libtheora-dev liblua5.3-dev build-essential gettext
```

the INSTALL says how to build. while desktop of Ubuntu is gnome we need this instructions (*maybe you need to do `autoreconf --install` before starting the first line.*):

```
autoreconf -f
./configure --with-gnome    #says --with-INTERFACE
make
make install
```

the first line done successfully.
but in configure step. we face the needed packages:

```
No package 'libgnomeui-2.0' found
No package 'gtk+-2.0' found
No package 'gtkglext-1.0' found
```

but I do not know how to install these packages. I can not find them.
How can I install these packages and finalize installation of Celesta?

Comment: It's not that Celestia *still* doesn't  have packages for Ubuntu. Celestia was DROPPED from Debian and Ubuntu around 2015-2016 when it seemed abandoned upstream. If the project has been reinvigorated, consider [packaging the software for Debian](https://mentors.debian.net), so it flows into Ubuntu.

Comment: several ways in: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1081299/how-can-i-install-celestia-on-ubuntu-18-04-1#answer-1163925

Answer (score 0):

Celestia was available somehow for Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and still available for [Debian Jessie](https://packages.debian.org/source/jessie/celestia).

In the whole FOSS world it is [spread well](https://repology.org/project/celestia/versions).

Official site [have](https://celestia.space/download.html) a link to [bintray repository](https://bintray.com/celestia/releases-deb/celestia/view/readmore#read). So you can install Celestia from it with commands below:

```
wget -O- https://bintray.com/user/downloadSubjectPublicKey?username=bintray | sudo apt-key add -
sudo add-apt-repository "deb https://dl.bintray.com/celestia/releases-deb bionic universe"
sudo apt-get install celestia
```

so there is no need to compile it from source.

---

Details about compilation:

1. The `libgnomeui-2.0` is a part of [`libgnomeui-dev` package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=disco&arch=any&mode=filename&searchon=contents&keywords=libgnomeui-2.0.pc), which is not available for 19.10. So you can't install this package on the *Eoan* system in easy way.
2. The `gtk+-2.0` is contained in `libgtk2.0-dev` which is [still available for 19.10](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=eoan&arch=amd64&mode=filename&searchon=contents&keywords=gtk%2B-2.0.pc).
3. The `gtkglext-1.0` is contained in `libgtkglext1-dev` which is [still available for 19.10](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?mode=filename&suite=eoan&section=all&arch=amd64&keywords=gtkglext-1.0.pc&searchon=contents)